# Laravel putting the return of a trait array into the controller

Tags: laravel

I'm currently struggling with how to return a variables from a trait and it should be returned in the array to be used in the controller:
Trait:

```
public function getAllData($search)
{
    if ($search->search == null) {
        $search->search = '#technology';
    }
    $cb = new Codebird();
    $cb->setConsumerKey(env('TwitterKey'), env('TwitterSecret'));
    $cb->setToken(env('AccessToken'), env('AccessTokenSecret'));

    //https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline
    //https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets
    $params = [
        'q' => $search->search,
        'lang' => 'en',
        'count' => '5',
    ];

    $reply = (array)$cb->search_tweets($params);
    $data = (array)$reply['statuses'];
    $s = count($reply['statuses']);
    return [
        'data' => $data,
        's' => $s,
    ];
```

Controller:
    public function TwitterData(Request $search) {

```
    $data = $this->getAllData($search);
    return view('front.search', compact('data'));
}
```

It currently gives me an error saying about using the object however I can't access the 'data' in the array

Error:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterProject\resources\views\front\search.blade.php)

Comment: You are trying to get a property of an object(in your view) that doesn't exists. But we don't have your view `C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterProject\resources\views\front\search.blade.php` and the line number. So this question is pretty hard to answer...

Comment: Error messages are'nt monsters, they are there to help YOU. Read the error and think about where in your code it make senses, also look the line of the error.

"Trying to get property of non-object". Your problem was said by PHP error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an array on your `getAllData` method, but you are probably trying to access it as an object on your View:

WRONG:

```
{!! $data->data !!}
```

RIGHT:

```
{!! $data['data'] !!}
```